# Intuition for when to use larger convolutional kernels

Tags: conv-neural-network

Although this question in some form has been asked in many places, I still have yet to read an answer or explanation that grants intuition for when it is appropriate to use larger kernels in a convolutional neural network. It seems like smaller kernels like 3x3 are all the rage these days, and I'll often hear things like, "it allows for more expressive power" or "can pick up on finer details" but this seems opposite to me. Shouldn't larger kernels always have greater expressive power (assuming same number of layers and at a greater computational cost, of course)?

For example, let's say I'd like to discriminate between very small features, such as detecting computer typeface. Should this warrant larger or smaller kernels?

Edit: As a quick test I built a 1 layer convolutional auto encoder and as far as I can tell, lower loss and better output from visual inspection of the decoded images are highly correlated with larger filters. So this seems to support my intuition that information is lost after pooling that no matter how many 3x3s we stack with the additional non-linear transformations, it will never be able to capture the information we could have learned if we used a larger filter. Would love some confirmation on this, though.

Comment: I am fairly ignorant of CNNs, but my impression was that there is usually some analogue of scale space? (e.g. small filters become "long range" at higher levels of an image pyramid). Also, for low-level feature detection/description, a smaller size at the lowest level could be better for invariance at the higher levels? (e.g. detect corners or t-junctions say, rather than entire letters)

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it: larger kernels = more parameters = allows for more expressive power.

Another way to see it, using texts as inputs to the CNN:

[image]

In this example, $x_i$ corresponds to the $i^{th}$ word. The kernel's width is 3: the larger its width, the more words it "sees" at once, which allows for more expressive power.

Smaller: risk of underfit; larger: risk of overfit. One needs to choose a size between too small and too large by simply trying. There is no method of finding the optimal number: people empirically try and see (e.g., using cross-validation). The most common search techniques are random, manual, and grid searches.

To choose the kernel size, one intuition: ask yourself how much contiguous data you would like to use if you had to engineer features. For example, if you use CNN for sentiment analysis and think that typically 3-grams or below are enough to capture the sentiment, then a kernel with or 3 would be a good choice.

Comment: Can you clarify how this translates to "when to use smaller vs. larger" filter size? (i.e. a naive reading of this answer could be "bigger is always better")

Comment: @GeoMatt22 sure, added

Comment: (+1) I agree in practice it would be best to explore a range of sizes and evaluate empirically. I interpreted the OP's question on "intuition" as something like "If we look at successful applications of CNNs, and the kernel sizes they ended up using, are there any qualitative relationships between optimal size and application domain?". It could be the answer is no, though!

Comment: I could imagine something like: large  kernels may appear to work well on synthetic "clean" datasets where the risk of over-fitting is low, but then perform worse on "real" problems?

Comment: GeoMatt22 has interpreted my question correctly. "Evaluate empirically" is basically the answer I've found in other places. Is this to say that intuition doesn't exist? The comment to the original question is also important: "a smaller size at the lowest level could be better for invariance at the higher levels? (e.g. detect corners or t-junctions say, rather than entire letters)" Do you have any thoughts on these points?

Comment: @jstaker7 I've added one more paragraph to try to address this.